# Create custom collector in java

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have two classes Meeting and Guest.

The relation looks like this:

```
class Meeting {

private LocalDate date;
private List<Guest> guests;

}
```

I need to get one Meeting by date and where guests are from the USA using stream.

I have List and I have done the next one:

```
List<Meeting> meetings = new ArrayList<>();

public Meeting getByDay(LocalDate date) {
    List<Guest> guests = getGuestsByDate(date).stream()
            .filter(guest-> guest.getCountry().equals("USA"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new Meeting(date, guests);
}
```

but now I need to refactor my code with custom Collector, which returns Meeting.
I read it needs to implement the Collector interface or  Collector.of() method but how it must look in my case? I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: `getGuestsByDate(date)` would be more fun to know the implementation of.

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.toList())` → `.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), l->new Meeting(date,l)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend this approach, but if you need, you can use:

```java
    Meeting m = Stream.of(new Guest(), new Guest())
        .collect(Collector.of(
            () -> new Meeting(date),
            Meeting::addGuest,
            (m1, m2) -> {
              ArrayList<Guest> guestsAll = new ArrayList<>(m1.getGuests());
              guestsAll.addAll(m2.getGuests());
              return new Meeting(date, guestsAll);
            }
        ));
```

I added couple of constructors and method to `Meeting` class

```java
    Meeting(LocalDate date) {
      this.date = date;
      this.guests = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    Meeting(LocalDate date, List<Guest> guests) {
      this.date = date;
      this.guests = guests;
    }

    public void addGuest(Guest g) {
      guests.add(g);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is about using `Collector`, you can use `reduce` operator as well. Try the below code:

```
public Meeting getByDay(LocalDate date) {   
    return getGuestsByDate(date).stream()
            .filter(guest -> guest.getCountry().equals("USA"))
            .reduce(new Meeting(date, new ArrayList<>()), (meeting, guest) -> {
                meeting.guests.add(guest);
                return meeting;
            }, (meeting1, meeting2) -> {
                meeting1.guests.addAll(meeting2.guests);
                return meeting1;
            });
}
```

You can shift those lambda expressions into the Meeting class or some other method and use method reference or one liner lambdas.

Answer (score -1):

I know this will not the full code but you will get an idea of how you can achieve the solution

```
 List<Meeting> meeting = meetings.stream()
        .filter(guest-> guest.getCountry().equals("USA"))
        .map(v->{ 
          return new Meeting(something, something);
         })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This code will return multiple meetings. Original code returns one meeting with multiple guests.

Comment: Ok bro, In that case, you need to return the map. For returning a single object type you can't use a collector. This is for the Map and list related return type. your existing code is fine.

Comment: Collector can return single object.

Comment: Collector<MyData, MyResult, MyResult> myCollector = Collector.of(
        () -> new MyResult(),
        (a, e) -> {
            if (e.key.equals("2")) {
                a.color = e.value;
            }
        },
        (a1, a2) -> null, // Not used, therefore not working scaffold
        a -> a
);
MyResult result = collection.stream().collect(myCollector);